# Identify patterns to create groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this:

```
create table t (a varchar2(30), b date);

insert into t values (NULL,TO_DATE('2017/01/01 00:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values (NULL,TO_DATE('2017/01/01 01:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values ('AAAA',TO_DATE('2017/01/01 02:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values (NULL,TO_DATE('2017/01/01 02:30:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values ('AAAA',TO_DATE('2017/01/01 03:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values (NULL,TO_DATE('2017/01/01 04:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values ('AAAA',TO_DATE('2017/01/01 04:30:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values (NULL,TO_DATE('2017/01/01 05:00:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into t values ('AAAA',TO_DATE('2017/01/01 05:30:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

I need to assign a group number for each repeating pattern of the TEXT field. The pattern I am looking for is "AAAA - null - AAAA". I want to be able to ignore any other 'nulls' outside of this pattern. In essence, looking to assign a group number like this:

```
a          b                GROUP
(null)     1/1/2017 0:00    IGNORE FROM ASSIGNING GROUP #
(null)     1/1/2017 1:00    IGNORE FROM ASSIGNING GROUP #
AAAA       1/1/2017 2:00      1
(null)     1/1/2017 2:30      1 
AAAA       1/1/2017 3:00      1
(null)     1/1/2017 4:00    IGNORE FROM ASSIGNING GROUP #
AAAA       1/1/2017 4:30      2
(null)     1/1/2017 5:00      2
AAAA       1/1/2017 5:30      2
```

I would like the data to look like this:

```
a        b                GROUP
AAAA     1/1/2017 2:00    1
(null)   1/1/2017 2:30    1
AAAA     1/1/2017 3:00    1
AAAA     1/1/2017 4:30    2
(null)   1/1/2017 5:00    2
AAAA     1/1/2017 5:30    2
```

Oracle SQL version:

Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: In the middle table you wrote `IGNORE FROM ASSIGNING GROUP #`, but then in the output you show those rows are **not included at all**. They are not just ignored "from assigning group number", they are ignored in their entirety. So, which is your requirement - exclude those rows from the output altogether? Then: What needs to be done with rows when the text in column `a` is not null, then a few rows have `null`, and then there is DIFFERENT text in column `a`? Ignore all of that? So, in the output, only include rows between "first" and "second" occurrence of same text?

Comment: Do you ever have two AAAAs in adjacent rows?  If so, what do you do?  Can there be other values in the a column?

Comment: The 'a' column only has "AAAA" and "null" values. The pattern (or set of rows) I am trying to identify is "AAAA - null - AAAA". If there's a "null" before or after this pattern, those rows would not part of this pattern, and therefore would not require a group #. The next group number should get assigned when it encounters the pattern "AAAA - null - AAAA" in the data set. Does that make sense?

Comment: There would not be two adjacent "AAAA" values. "AAAA" will always be followed by a "null".

Comment: I attempted to identify patterns using Lag/Lead functions & assign group numbers using Dense_Rank. But the issue I am running into is it's including the rows that I wish to IGNORE as part of a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: The only possible values in column `a` are `'AAAA'` and `null`. The number of `'AAAA'` values may be odd (in which case the last one does NOT start a new group, it is ignored along with all the `null` rows before and after it). There are no duplicate date-times in column `b`.

With these assumptions: First, we keep a running count of `'AAAA'` values, as well as the total count, using analytic `count()` in a subquery. Then we adjust the group number (computed easily from the running count) in the `select` clause of the outer query, and we use the running count (for `null` in column `a`) and the total count (for `'AAAA'` in column `a`) in the `where` clause, to determine which rows to keep in the output.

The code follows this logical solution description very closely.

```
select a, b, ceil(c/2) as grp
from   (
  select a, b, count(a) over (order by b) as c, count(a) over () as max_c
  from   t
)
where  a is     null and c <  max_c and mod(c, 2) = 1
   or  a is not null and c <= 2 * trunc(max_c/2)
;

A    B                GRP
---- ---------------- ---
AAAA 2017/01/01 02:00   1
     2017/01/01 02:30   1
AAAA 2017/01/01 03:00   1
AAAA 2017/01/01 04:30   2
     2017/01/01 05:00   2
AAAA 2017/01/01 05:30   2
```

For fun, and to illustrate the benefits of upgrading to Oracle 12, here is how this can be done, very easily, with the `match_recognize` clause (added in 12.1):

```
select a, b, grp
from   t
match_recognize(
  order by b
  measures match_number() as grp
  all rows per match
  pattern  ( h x*? h )
  define   h as h.a = 'AAAA'
);
```

Comment: This helped provide the direction I needed, I will work on applying this logic to my dataset and see if it works. And yes, I did read about match_recognize before and I am waiting patiently for the 12c upgrade (if we ever decide to do that!).

Comment: @user8914489 - the `match_recognize` solution may not help you today, but when I post answers, I do what I can to help other forum members as well (who may have a similar question and who may have Oracle 12 already). Please feel free to come back with follow-up questions after you use your solution in your real-life scenario.